# How to send a text file through bluetooth from internal storage in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, share

I created a text file in internal storage and I want to share the file through the bluetooth with a paired device.

How can I do this? I tried the following code, but not working

```
private void WriteFile(String text, Context context, String deviceAddress)
    {
        try {

            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("command.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            fos.write(text.getBytes());
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "command.txt");
            if (file.exists())
               Toast.makeText(context, "command file created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "command file not created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(BluetoothShare.URI, "content://" + Uri.fromFile(file));
            values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION, deviceAddress);
            values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
            Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
            values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
            context.getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);


            Toast.makeText(context, "Command sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting File unknown, file not sent error.

what shall I do?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the error in question as well.

Comment: Thanks husker, actually the error I got File Unknown, file not sent

Comment: good, but for more clearification, you should post your DDMS's error by copy & paste, that will give clear idea to other users.

Comment: I got the same error, have you got any solution. although I was able to send the file from external storage